# Is "sync" before drop_caches necessary?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cache

I have read a lot of docs saying, it is good idea to do a `sync` before doing `echo [1,2,3] > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. 
I am not able to understand why it is needed, since drop_cache is a non-destructive operation, and dirty data is not going to be deleted by drop_cache.
I have also seen a behavior where `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` first commit dirty data back to disk and then frees the cache. This is seen through `/proc/meminfo` "Dirty" & "Writeback".

Comment: "I have read a lot of docs saying ..." Could you link to such a doc?

Comment: Sure, Linux Kernel Documentation about "vm" subsystem

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Excerpt - drop_caches

Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, dentries and
inodes from memory, causing that memory to become free.

To free pagecache:
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free dentries and inodes:
 echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:
 echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

As this is a non-destructive operation and dirty objects are not freeable, the
user should run `sync' first.

Answer (score 7):

Anyways I got the answer on stackoverflow which I corroborated by doing a small experiment.

"sync" only makes dirty cache to clean cache. cache is still preserved.
drop_caches doesn't touch dirty caches and only drops clean caches.
So to make all memory free, it is necessary to do sync first before drop_caches in case flushing daemons hasn't written the changes to disk.

My blog about this little experiment -

[What are exactly O_DIRECT, O_SYNC Flags, Buffers & Cached in Linux-Storage I/O?](https://web.archive.org/web/20131123025811/http://www.thesubodh.com/2013/07/what-are-exactly-odirect-osync-flags.html)

Stackoverflow link -

[“sync” before drop_caches,is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500134/sync-before-drop-caches-is-it-necessary)